# Probability: Rolling a pair of dice

Tags: probability

In a gambling game, a woman rolls two fair dice. If she rolls a double $6$, she will win $\$50$, If she get a double other than $(6, 6)$, she will win $\$5$. she loses otherwise. How much should she pay to play if the game is fair? (round it to the nearest cents)
choose the best answer: 
  $$\$2.08\\
  \$3.00\\
  \$5.00\\
  \$2.22$$

Answer (score 2):

a fair price is equal to the expected payout . since every double has a probability $\frac{1}{36}$ we have ..

$$E(x) = \sum_i x_iP(x_i) = 50(\frac{1}{36}) + 5(\frac{5}{36})= \frac{75}{36} $$